# How to find the k-th largest element effiently in a set while the set may be varied with time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are some queries to ask the k-th largest element in the set.

And There are some updates to add,delete or change the element.

How to do this task effeciently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: @srikfreak but the element may be varied? I know O(n) selection...

Comment: @Dukeling the BST may be too slow for that? It may take O(n) to complete a query or update. And it is as slow as just search the set in computational complexity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (modified for each node to store the size of the subtree from that node) should do the trick.

Find k-th largest will take `O(log n)` time.

Add, remove and update (remove, then add) will each take <= `O(log^2 n)` time (or possibly just `O(log n)`).

Depending on how the data is looked up, you may need an array or hash-map with pointers into the BST (for the update operation).

Find k-th largest will look something like:

```
Node findKthLargest(Node node, int k)
  if (node.left != null)
    if (k <= node.left.count)
      return findKthLargest(node.left, k)
    else
      k -= node.left.count
  if (k == 0)
    return node
  if (node.right != null)
    return findKthLargest(node.right, k)
```

Since it can't explore both `left` and `right`, it's clear to see that it only takes `O(log n)` time.

Add, remove and update will have to modify the appropriate counts of subtrees, but only those higher up in the tree. Because with a Balanced Binary Search Tree, these operations (without count modification) each take `O(log n)` time, and with the count modification, you only do `O(log n)` extra work (to go up the tree) at each of the `O(log n)` steps, so obviously it can't take more than `O(log^2 n)`.

Comment: Wow. Really Thanks, I will try to implement it by myself.